# Link react-native-fbsdk with CocoaPods as of 24/12/2017?

Tags: react-native, cocoapods, react-native-fbsdk

So the docs changed again
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native/configure-ios

I was able to accomplish the task a few days ago but the docs were different.

They say to run:

```
react-native install react-native-fbsdk
react-native link react-native-fbsdk
```

- Doesn't `install` also trigger `link`?
- Doing this produces a red error like `Native component for 'RCTFBLikeView' does not exist`